# How to reload a class file in Jython

Tags: java, jython

I'd like to reload a Java class file into Jython after modifying the Java source and recompiling.

All my searches on the topic redirect [here](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jreload.html), but the `jreload` module isn't included in version 2.7.0.

I need an equivalent of Python's `imp.reload`.

Comment: Does this help?

Most of the jreload functions are contained within ihooks in V2.7.

from [Deprecated library modules in Jython V2.7](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_jython27.html#rxml_jython27__sec1)

Comment: I tried ihooks extensively; can't get it to work.